# HTML can send Form without anything in E-Mail

Tags: html, forms, email-validation

so we´re doing a basic HTML site in School,

i got the Following Problem:

I want to do a form where you have to put in your E-Mail Adress, so i used:

<input type="email" ....>

when i type in anything thats not an E-Mail Adress, it gives me an error when i try to send,

allthough when i send it without anything typed in it just sends it,

i tried minlenght="5" still same Problem.

thanks for your help

Marvin Letsche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add required to your input field

```
<input type="email" .... required>
```